# Simple reducer accumulator should not be mutating the state, why is it?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

For some reason my reducer is only returning a single element in the `categories` collection.

I'm just learning this accumlator logic, so I have kept it simple which I thought was suppose to simply return the exact same state as I started with.

My state in JSON looks like:

```
{     
 "account":{  
    "id":7,    
    "categories":[  
       {  
          "id":7,          
          "products":[  
             {                  
                "productId":54                
             }
          ]
       },
       {  
          "id":9,          
          "products":[  
             {                  
                "productId":89                
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
}
```

In my reducer I have the following:

```
return {
  ...state,
  account: {
      ...state.account,
      categories: [state.account.categories.reduce((acc, cat) => {
        return {...acc, ...cat}
      }, {})]
    }
  };
```

When I output my state, I see that for some reason it has removed one of the `categories` from the collection.

Why isn't my state the same since the accumulator isn't filtering anything?  It should be the exact same as it started with.

Comment: you are spreading cat object in the return. should be `{...acc, cat}`

Comment: also it's not the same state: you convert array into one object enclosed in an array

Comment: @marzelin here is a working example of the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/62r8jl4lpn

Comment: If you want to return the same array but a different reference you could use `state.account.categories.slice()` or even `[...state.account.categories]`, both are accepted ways of doing it. Using `reduce` might be confusing in this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to return categories unchanged (but with a different reference), you should do it like this:

```
categories: state.account.categories.reduce((acc, cat) => {
        return [...acc, cat];
      }, [])
```

In your code accumulator value is an object with categories props that is constantly overwritten by another item from an array so in the end only the last item is present.

Let's put aside react and redux and focus on `reduce` function. It takes an array and returns something different using the function called a reducer.

In the following example:

```
const array = [{num: 1}, {num: 2}];
```

you can take each of the elements of an array and merge their properties:

```
array.reduce((acc, item) => ({...acc, ...item}), {})
```

this is equal to

```
Object.assign({}, array[0], array[1]);
```

or

```
{...array[0], ...array[1]}
```

and result is `{num: 2}`, (first there was an empty object `{}`, then `{num: 1}` and finally `{...{num: 1}, ...{num: 2}}` gave `{num: 2}`

It doesn't matter if you enclose it in an array, it's still a one object created from merging all objects in the array together

If you want a copy of an array. This can be done like this:

```
array.reduce((acc, item) => [...acc, item], []);
```

This is equal to

```
[].concat(...array);
```

Comment: Thanks!  So say I wanted to filter further like here https://codesandbox.io/s/x76ml37jjo  what is the syntax issue I have been stuck on this for a long time!

Comment: @Blankman If you want to get a list of categories without one chosen element (with id 9) you can use filter (you can use reduce also but it is more verbose) https://codesandbox.io/s/p5w57jnqrm

Comment: @Blankman I'd recommend to pluck out those reducer functions, test them in isolation and when you see they work as you expect put them in react code. Debugging them when they're wrapped in all those react/redux code must be frustrating.

Comment: I appreciate your tips!  Any idea what the syntax issue is with mine? It is bugging me.

Comment: @Blankman you have something like this: `[ cat: arr.filter]`. This is an array, you can't do that, property assignment is for objects `{ cat: val}`. Check this fixed example where we filter out product with productId 89: https://codesandbox.io/s/1rp2lpzy13

Comment: the codestandbox has an error in it, maybe you didn't click save?

Comment: @Blankman btw. you should create reducers for each prop down in the object. What you're now doing (reaching a few levels down to change one value) is unmanageable because you have to keep in mind the whole object structure at once.

Comment: Yes, I am going to create a git branch and totally re-work my state tomorrow!  Just want to get this working first, which it is now thanks man!